# control vlc with python

Tags: python, vlc

I would need two things in vlc that I want to control from a Python script. First is to open a network stream, add the stream address as a url in it and play it. (This might be skippable)

The second thing is to take a snapshot at a specific time and use that picture. As I saw the different kind of libraries and modules, they can only things like play, pause, rewind a video.

Can anybody help me with this one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what prevents you from using `subprocess` module and calling vlc from command line?

Comment: That's a great idea, but I've never used vlc from command line yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.chdir(path)` and `os.system(command)`

Find where your vlc executable (.exe) is, and store the path in a variable.
Then you can use os.system to execute a given command.

[Here you see a list of possible command-line options for VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/)

Example code:

```
import os

vlc_path = "C:\path\to\vlc"
net_stream = "http://host[:port]/file" # You can use other protocols too

os.chdir(vlc_path)
os.system(f"vlc {net_stream}")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I will have a look at this list.

Comment: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc' is the path to vlc but when I run your 5 lines of code in Python 3.6 I get this error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc' When I change the slash to backslash Python doubles the slashes and does not find the correct way obviously. What can be the solution? Thanks

Comment: Try omitting the trailing `vlc` in your path. (`vlc_path = "'C:/Program Files (x86)/VideoLAN/VLC`")

Comment: Thanks very much! My last question: When I open a cmd and type in the following: vlc http://stream.*****/playlist.m3u8 --rate=1 --video-filter=scene --vout=dummy --start-time=10 --stop-time=11 --scene-format=png --scene-ratio=24 --scene-prefix=snap --scene-path=C:\Users\*****\ vlc://quit
 It works perfectly. But when I try to do it in python like this: import os

os.system('vlc http://stream...\ vlc://quit')
 vlc and cmd come up but the files don't get created in the target folder. What can be the problem? Thx

Comment: (In Python 3 it works perfectly, in Python 2 the problem is still up)